# Convert lambda expression to string

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda, c#-4.0

This may seem like an odd request, however with APIs that require a filter property string I thought it would be a nice concept to be able to convert a provided type safe lambda expression which could then be compiled into a query string - similar in essence to Linq -> SQL.

So for example:

```
 Func<TQueryObj, bool> 
 (invoice) => { invoice.Status == "DRAFT" && invoice.Type == "ACCREF" };
```

Would convert to

```
 Status=="DRAFT" && Type=="ACCREF"
```

I'm using an invoicing API at the moment hence the example. Any means of achieving this fairly simply?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You need to make an inherited [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx), which will recursively crawl through an `Expression<Func<...>>`.
It won't be easy.